# Ticks on the y axis not working as anticipated

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-pic, ticks

I am trying to have a plot where the ticks on the y axis are 1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, and 1.02. However, only the ticks 1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.02, 1.02 are shown in the figure (see below).
I was under the assumption that if we write ytick={1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, 1.02} then that sets the values written at each y tick in the figure. Could someone please explain to me why this is wrong and furthermore how to have it so that the ticks in the y axis are for 1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, and 1.02 ?
My code is here:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[name=plot, ymin=1, xtick={0, ..., 10}, ytick={1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, 1.02}, xlabel={\LARGE$b_1$}]
            \addplot[black, mark=*]
            table{./data/ratio_of_estimated_value_versus_optimal_value.txt};\label{ratio_estimated_value_versus_optimal_value}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \caption{Ratio of the Estimated Value of the Game and the Optimal Value of the Game}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You've got a table data included here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the decimal numbers to show up properly you should set `precision=4` for displaying upto four significant figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, scaled y ticks=false, fixed, precision=4}} %<------------ Here
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[name=plot, xtick={0, ..., 10}, ytick={1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, 1.02}, xlabel={\LARGE$b_1$}]
            \addplot[black, mark=*]
            table{./table.txt};\label{ratio_estimated_value_versus_optimal_value}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \caption{Ratio of the Estimated Value of the Game and the Optimal Value of the Game}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Precision missing]

Comment: Bromuela thanks, that works! I don't quite understand a few things though. In the style curly braces (in the \pgfplotsset command), what do the "fixed" and "/pgf/number format/.cd" statements do? Thanks

Comment: `pgf/number format/.cd` sets the default path to `/pgf/number format`. This allows you to call all the subkeys at once without needing to call everytime. Example: Instead of calling `/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=2`, you can shorten them to `/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=2`. And `fixed` just rounds the number to the fixed number of digits after decimal point. In this problem you really don't need it. You can use `fixed zerofill` instead to show trailing zeroes.

Comment: Since this solved your problem, you may give a tick mark to this answer. I will appreciate greatly. Regards.